# How do I change the splash screen on an app built with Trigger.io?

Tags: forge, trigger.io

I have started building an app with Trigger.io but before releasing it I want to customize it with our own splash screen rather than the default one that appears with the Trigger.io Forge promotion. Is that possible?

Thanks!

Comment: This should help you out - http://docs.trigger.io/en/v1.2/config.html#field-launch-images

Answer (score 6):

Yes. You can change the splash screen by altering the launch image in the config file and running **forge build** again.

The documentation is here:
http://docs.trigger.io/en/v1.2/config.html#field-launch-images

Comment: Note that in version 1.3 onwards of Trigger.io, launch images are a separate module: http://docs.trigger.io/en/v1.3/modules/launchimage.html

Comment: Although they look similar, here are the docs for 1.4: http://docs.trigger.io/en/v1.4/modules/launchimage.html